# Is it Ok to call cy.server() twice in same test in Cypress

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

```
it('Some Test', () => {
  cy.server();
  cy.route('POST', 'my/api1').as('myApi');
  ...
  cy.wait('@api1');

  cy.server();
  cy.route('POST', 'my/api2').as('myApi');
  ...
  cy.wait('@api2');
}
```

Is this code ok, like is there any problem if we are calling cy.server() twice in the same test?in Cypress

Answer (score 2):

I did code as above to see if there is any repercussion, however, couldn't get any!

Basically I wanted to abstract it away in a function like this

```
Cypress.Commands.add('listenRoute', (type, url, alias) => {
    cy.server();
    cy.route({
        method: type,
        url,
    }).as(alias);
});
```

So I got tests successfully passing without any errors or warning, and thus am concluding, that it is OK

Comment: What tests did you run? For instance, did you try to `cy.wait('@api1')` after `cy.listenRoute('get', url, 'api2')`?

Comment: Good Question Richard, what I tried is listenroute(,,'api1') listenroute(,,'api2) then an action that makes ap1 xhr, then cy.wait('@api1'); then api2 xhr,  then cy.wait('@api2'); and it ran perfectly well as well

Answer (score 1):

The second `cy.server();` call is not required as you are waiting `cy.wait('@myApi');` for the previous call to complete. Also, the second route is the same as the first, therefore no need to set again if server() is not re-instantiated.

[Doco](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/server.html#Notes):

> Outstanding requests are automatically aborted between tests

Therefore you need to either wait for previous to complete, or initiate a second server to run concurrently.

```
it('Some Test', () => {
  cy.server();
  cy.route('POST', 'my/api').as('myApi');
  ...
  cy.wait('@myApi');
  cy.wait('@myApi');
  cy.visit('@myApi');
  cy.wait('@myApi');
  cy.visit('@myApi');      
}
```

Comment: thank you for answer, however I wanted to ask if there is any repercussion of calling cy.server() twice in a same test